# Android asmack how set invisible

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

in android Asmack i want to set invisible user.
and i used from every mode but it didn't works. after that i used from Type ..

when i set type unavailable, it works . but there is a problem .. my pocket listener doesn't work .. and i cant get any thing from user .. What can i do .. Thanks a lot.

```
Type type = Presence.Type.available;
                    Mode OWN = Mode.available;
                    if (DB_STATUS.avibilaty.toString().equals("")) {
                        OWN = Mode.available;
                    } else if (DB_STATUS.avibilaty.toString().equals("away")) {
                        OWN = Mode.away;
                    } else if (DB_STATUS.avibilaty.toString().equals(
                            "available")) {
                        OWN = Mode.available;
                    } else if (DB_STATUS.avibilaty.toString().equals(
                            "unavailable")) {
                        type = Presence.Type.unavailable;
                    } else if (DB_STATUS.avibilaty.toString().equals("busy")) {
                        OWN = Mode.dnd;
                    }

                    Presence presence = new Presence(type);
                    presence.setMode(OWN);
```